# Create ASP.NET Core Web API and infinite main cycle

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am still new to C#. What I want to do is to create application that use more cores for example via Task with nonstop calculations and communicate two way via some API.

The problem is that I don't know if I should choose console app and add API somehow or create an ASP.NET Core Web API and add new task.

What is correct approach and how can I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET uses a concept called `HostedService` for these kind of tasks.

A good reference to start reading is the official docs at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers?pivots=dotnet-8-0

So in your case I would go for a "WebApi" / "ASP.NET core" Project using a `HostedService` in Background and adding a MessageBus / Event System to communicate with the background service via API calls.

To be more flexible, you could outsource your calculations into an extra project of type class library, so that it can also be used in a command line app.

An example could be:

```cs
// Program.cs
// ...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ...
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
```

whereas `MyHostedService` is gonna implement `IHostedService` or extend one of it's derivates `BackgroundService`:

```cs
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }
    // ... implement interface methods ...
}
```

Comment: This seems interesting will definitely try.